# How to find average of matching key values of dictionaries in a list in python

Tags: python

```
[{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 334632,"memorybytes": 5467234},    
{"name": "thisisname2", "filebytestotal": 2351, "memorybytes": 324523},    
{"name": "thisisname3", "filebytestotal": 2314651, "memorybytes": 2235},    
{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 13432, "memorybytes": 546534},    
{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 32342, "memorybytes": 341234}]
```

Hello everyone, I try to figure out how I can make the average value of the keys filebytes and memorybytes for all matching "name" values. 
My problem is I don´t get how to search for patterns through the dictionaries in the total list that it is.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please provide some code you try and result you want to get.

Comment: and why you try to do the same questions without analyse yours fails?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305169/how-to-make-average-of-matching-keyvalues-of-dictionaries-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: I am sorry, its my first question here and I thought with "put-on-hold" it wasn´t online anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could approach this problem is by restructuring it into a dictionary of lists. Something like

```
list_of_dicts = [{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 334632,"memorybytes": 5467234},    
{"name": "thisisname2", "filebytestotal": 2351, "memorybytes": 324523},    
{"name": "thisisname3", "filebytestotal": 2314651, "memorybytes": 2235},    
{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 13432, "memorybytes": 546534},    
{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 32342, "memorybytes": 341234}]

# reshape
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_lists = defaultdict(list)
for obj in list_of_dicts:
    dict_of_lists[obj['name']].append({
        'bytestotal': obj['filebytestotal'],
        'memorybytes': obj['memorybytes'],
    })

dict_of_lists
> {'thisisname1': [{'bytestotal': 334632, 'memorybytes': 5467234}, ...], ...}

# and now calculate your averages
for key, totals_list in dict_of_lists.items():
    bytes_total = [obj['bytestotal'] for obj in totals_list]
    bytes_total_avg = sum(bytes_total) / len(bytes_total)
    print(key, bytes_total_avg)
    # and the same for memory bytes
```

This uses [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) which populates any empty keys with a default value. You can write it with built-in dictionaries, but this saves you a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example with the "memorybytes" key.

```
dic = [{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytes": 334632,"memorybytes": 5467234},{"name": "thisisname2", "filebytestotal": 2351, "memorybytes": 324523},{"name": "thisisname3", "filebytestotal": 2314651, "memorybytes": 2235},{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 13432, "memorybytes": 546534},{"name": "thisisname1", "filebytestotal": 32342, "memorybytes": 341234}]

pattern_name = "1"
all_memorybytes = [element['memorybytes'] for element in dic if pattern_name in element['name'] ]
avg_memorybytes = sum(all_memorybytes) / float(len(all_memorybytes))
print avg_memorybytes
```

With the filebytestotal there are a problem since you have two diferent keys:
"filebytes" and "filebytestotal". If u have this key in all the elments of the array then you could use the same functionality by changing the key in the comprehension list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it´s way more complicated what I meant :D 
pattern_name should be automatically found. Like when "name" is more than 1 time in dic, then take it as a pattern and find the average of all its values. 
And that shoud be done with every "name". And sorry for the filebytes - that was a typo, it should always bethe same keys.